# Was anyone helping Tress covertly?

Tags: cosmere, tress-of-the-emerald-sea

At one point in *Tress of  the Emerald Sea*, the title character notes to herself how up until that point, she had been almost ridiculously lucky, and that events had seemingly always aligned in her favor.

Of course, Tress does have a tendency to downplay her own intelligence and courage—much of her "good luck" was either her being outrageous enough to try something plausibly lethal or perceptive enough to grasp a crucial detail—but it is true that a number of events had to align for everything to have gone just right. Most notably, Captain Crow and her crew had to just *happen* to raid exactly the ship that Tress and Charlie were on, and Charlie had to just *happen* to have been on the ship that Tress stowed away on.

Hoid was not in any state to consciously plot, but we know that there are quite a number of entities in the Cosmere that might be interested in setting events in motion for Hoid to become an Elantrian, including several of divine power. We also know that Hoid [uses Fortune to know where to go](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Fortune), and one might imagine that some elements of this could work even with the curse active.

Was there any force helping Tress behind the scenes?

Comment: Well, obviously Hoid, Ulaam and Charlie were helping her, that's obvious, but how much did they help and how is not? Another thing is that's supposed to be in-universe story and we don't know how reliable narrator Hoid is. He might have been "incapacitated", but we're not clear on the details.

Comment: @Mithoron - Right, but I figure that Hoid was barely in any shape to make conscious plans, Ulaam figured that Hoid would get better eventually and so was not doing much, and Charlie really couldn't have had much influence over her good luck except in the parts that I mentioned.

Comment: Charlie was there because he wanted to find her, Hoid used Fortune, Ulaam followed him - all were there because they wanted. If their meeting there was otherwise helped, we don't know. As far as Hoid is concerned, I would expect him to use a bit of emotional Allomancy from time to time.

Comment: @Mithoron - Not in the state he is in!

Comment: You can use Allomancy not even knowing what you do, and Hoid could concentrate from time to time.